# How to render data from external database (Oracle) using datatables in Django Python?

Tags: django, python-3.x, oracle, datatables

I am retrieving data from a table in an external Oracle database and want to show data on web page using datatables. The retrieved data is in list form. Please suggest the way how to render list data in tabular form using datatables in Python Django.

Since I am connecting to external database and storing data in on single variable I am not able to find any solutions through standard models.py.

The code is not giving any error but empty table is being rendered on web page. My expectation is it should show desired data on web page in tabular form.

Please let me know of any other detail or code is required ?

```
#views.py
#Necessary imports
def show_data(request):
dsn_str = cx_Oracle.makedsn("<<HOSTNAME>>","<<PORT_NO>>","<<SCHEMA>>")
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="***", dsn=dsn_str
, encoding='UTF-8')
cursor=con.cursor()
cursor.execute("select abc, pqr, xyz from myDB.myTable")
data_set=cursor.fetchall()
con.close()
return render(request, 'index.html', {"form":data_set})
```

```
#index.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
   {% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">
   <table id = "table" class= "table table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ABC</th>
        <th>PQR</th>
        <th>XYZ</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {% for data in form %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ data.ABC }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.PQR }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.XYZ }}</td>
      </tr>
     {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: "external table" actually means something very specific in Oracle: [a database table whose data is stored in an OS file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E) rather than being managed inside the database. Is that what you're using? Or do you just mean the data comes from a database outside Django?

Comment: Yes data comes from a database outside django. By external table here I mean normal Oracle table I am referring through cx connection (not Python internal DB table) . Since my Oracle is 11g and django is v2.0 and both are incompatible so I can't configure Oracle in Python's db. I just want to extract data and render it in tabular form through datatable on web page.